# Sending data from one page to another, MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I had made a previous post regarding this and have been working on this issue for quite a while.

I am unable to pass data from page1 to page2. I have looked at various tutorials online but have not been able to get the desired result.

I am new to both MongoDB and PHP.
If someone could explain how I can query data from mongoDB.

Below I am posting the code for both pages

```
//LOGIN PAGE
<? PHP      
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Movie Database </title>
</head>

<?PHP

    try {
        // open connection to MongoDB server
        $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

        // access database
        $db = $conn->test;

        // access collection
        $collection = $db->items;

        // execute query
        $cursor = $collection->find();

        foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
            $correct = $obj['username'];
        }

        // disconnect from server
        $conn->close();
    } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
        die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }


?>


<body>
<br>
<center>
<h1> Welcome to Login Page </h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form action="page.php" METHOD="POST">
<label>Username :</label>
<input type="text" Name="username">
<br>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" Name="password">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
<br>
</center>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Second Page starts from here

```
 //PAGE 2
<?PHP
session_start();

    //$db = $conn->test;        

    //echo 'Username: ' . $_POST['username'] . '<br>';
    //echo 'Password: ' . $_POST['password'] . '<br>';

    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $userPass = $_POST['password'];

    $collection = $db->items;

    $userN   = array('username'=>$userName);
    $userP   = array('password'=>$userPass);

    $cursor  = $collection->find(array($userN,$userP));


    foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
        $foundUserN = $obj['username'];
        $foundUserP = $obj['password'];

        if($obj['username'] == $userName && $obj['password'] == $userPass){
            echo '<h1>FOUND</h1>';          
        }
        else{
            echo 'not found';           
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

    try {
    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

    $db = $conn->test;

    $conn->close();

    } 
    catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
        die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
    } 
    catch (MongoException $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should be hashing your passwords!

Answer (score -1):

Here are few points to note

1. Session not being used(simply started).
2. collecting information before establishing db connection.(returns NULL)

Check this link you will get some idea...

[Simple PHP mongoDB Username and Password Check for site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830735/simple-php-mongodb-username-and-password-check-for-site)

Now go ahead store user's id in session and then in any page start the session and keep using..

In PHP CODE goes like this:-

```
 <?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;//if match found
 ?>
```

In another file

```
 <?php
     session_start();
     echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
 ?>
```

enjoy cheers!!!!!